# Koala Facebook for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, koala, timeoutexception

How to raise timeout error using *koala* gem for *Facebook* in *Rails* ?

if anybody knows, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ruby's Timeout module as follows:

```
require 'timeout'
begin
   status = Timeout::timeout(5) do
      @koala_api.get_connection 'me', :feed
   end
rescue Timeout::Error
   # do something on timeout
end
```

Comment: Timeout: is not thread-safe. And can lead to unexpected. behavior in a multi-thread scenario as Kidd Said.

Comment: @NandoSousa you are just offending, because of you have not prooved you statement, so your opinion must be thrown to trash...

Comment: Take a look:
https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-ruby-dont-use-timeout-77d9d4e5a001
https://jvns.ca/blog/2015/11/27/why-rubys-timeout-is-dangerous-and-thread-dot-raise-is-terrifying/
https://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/

Don't be offended, be humble enough to accept that you're wrong instead.

Comment: @NandoSousa that papers show imagine on the topic only, without any proof, so thst is the only conjecture and speculations... so you can't indeed downvote because of proofless speculations

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is:
`Koala.http_service.http_options = {request: {open_timeout: 1, timeout: 1}}`